# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type bool 'System.Linq' and search, sort and paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I know this question has already been asked before but I think my case is a little more unique, which is why I'm here asking for help.

SO basically I have this table, ServerDB_ which contains the values ServerID (pk, fk), DatabaseID (pk, fk) InstanceName and Verified. For readability sake for the user, I wanted to show ServerName and DatabaseName from the Server_ table, and Database_ table, and allow the user to sort and search with these parameters as well.

This tutorial has been my godsend, but I'm finding it's limited.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

This is my code, which is not right and gets compiler errors. I've messed around and played with it a lot, but I'm kinda stuck. I'm just not sure how I can still get the sort, search and lastly the paging option to work, with different table values. My paging gives me an exception because of the other var values I added.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.IDSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "ServerID_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.ID2SortParm = sortOrder == "ID2" ? "DatabaseID_desc" : "ID";
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "Name" ? "ServerName_desc" : "Name";
        ViewBag.Name2SortParm = sortOrder == "Name2" ? "DatabaseName_desc" : "Name2";

        if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        var serverdb= from s in db.ServerDB_ //original var serverdb
                       select s;
        var server = from x in db.Server_ //created this for the Server_ values
                       select x;
        var database = from y in db.Database_ //created this for the Database_ values
                       select y;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) //newserverdb is what I made to hold the values from all the different tables
        {
          var  newserverdb = (serverdb.Where(s => s.ServerID.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                &&(server.Where(x => x.ServerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())));

        }


        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "ServerID_desc":
                serverdb = serverdb.OrderByDescending(s => s.ServerID);
                break;
            case "ID2":
                serverdb = serverdb.OrderBy(s=> s.DatabaseID);
                break;
            case "DatabaseID_desc":
                serverdb = serverdb.OrderByDescending(s => s.DatabaseID);
                break;
            case "Name":
                server = server.OrderBy(x => x.ServerName);
                break;
            case "ServerName_desc":
                server = server.OrderByDescending(x => x.ServerName);
                break;
            case "Name2":
                database = database.OrderBy(y => y.DatabaseName);
                break;
            case "DatabaseName_desc":
                database = database.OrderByDescending(y => y.DatabaseName);
                break;
            default:
                serverdb = serverdb.OrderBy(s =>s.ServerID);
                break;
        }


        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(newserverdb.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I'm sorry if my question is kind of hard to understand. I tried to put it as eloquently as possible, but this stuff is hard to understand.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve? You're currently declaring a new local variable in a block that *only* contains that variable declaration... (Ideally, you should reduce the problem to a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...)

Comment: I realized the local variable thing right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your second part of condition will return a `IEnumerable<T>`

```
server.Where(x => x.ServerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
```

Whereas your operator `&&` requires a boolean value on the right hand side.

Use `Enumerable.Any` like:

```
 var  newserverdb = (serverdb.Where(s => s.ServerID.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                &&(server.Any(x => x.ServerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())));
                       //^^^^^
```

I am not sure how would you use your query later in your code, since you have defined it inside an `if` block and it will only be visible there. So later when you do:

```
return View(newserverdb.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

You will get an error since `newserverdb` will not be visible here.

You can declare an `IQueryable<ServerDB_> newserverdb` outside of your `if` block and later use that, or you can move that whole block at the end of the method, and return from inside of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the Where to Any:

```
var  newserverdb = (serverdb.Where(s => s.ServerID.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                && (server.Any(x => x.ServerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())));
```